# how add behavior in expression blend

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

Hi
There is a behavior in following code 
I want to use this behavior in my WPF application 
But i cant attached this behavior to my project

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Brainsiders.MouseOver3D
{
    [Description("MouseOver3D - A behavior that applies the MouseOver Design Interaction Pattern to a 3D environment.")]
    public class MouseOver3D : TargetedTriggerAction<FrameworkElement>
    {        
        private TimeSpan hoverUp_duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
       [Category("Mouse Over 3D - Going Up")]
        public TimeSpan HoverUp_duration
        {
            get { return hoverUp_duration; }
            set { hoverUp_duration = value; }
        }
        private TimeSpan hoverDown_Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.9);
        [Category("Mouse Over 3D - Going Down")]
        public TimeSpan HoverDown_Duration
        {
            get { return hoverDown_Duration; }
            set { hoverDown_Duration = value; }
        }
        [Category("Mouse Over 3D - Going Up")]
        public IEasingFunction HoverUp_Easing { get; set; }
        [Category("Mouse Over 3D - Going Down")]
        public IEasingFunction HoverDown_Easing { get; set; }
        private double hoverOffset = 30;
        [Category("Mouse Over 3D - General")]
        public double HoverOffset
        {
            get { return hoverOffset; }
            set { hoverOffset = value; }
        }
        private FrameworkElement feAssociatedObject;
        private FrameworkElement feSourceObject;
        private FrameworkElement feTargetObject;
        private PlaneProjection ProjectionTargetObject;
        private Storyboard SB_HoverZ;
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            FrameworkElement myElement = this.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        }
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            feAssociatedObject = (FrameworkElement)this.AssociatedObject;
            feSourceObject = (FrameworkElement)this.AssociatedObject;
            feSourceObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(feSourceObject_Loaded);
        }
        void feSourceObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            feSourceObject.Loaded -= new RoutedEventHandler(feSourceObject_Loaded);
            ProjectionTargetObject = new PlaneProjection();
            feTargetObject = (FrameworkElement)this.TargetObject;
            if (feTargetObject == null) feTargetObject = feAssociatedObject;
            if (feTargetObject.Projection == null)
            {
                feTargetObject.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
                PlaneProjection pj = new PlaneProjection();
                feTargetObject.Projection = pj;
            }
            feSourceObject.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(feSourceObject_MouseEnter);
            feSourceObject.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(feSourceObject_MouseLeave); 
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
        }
        void feSourceObject_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            DeactivateAnimation();
        }
        void feSourceObject_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ActivateAnimation();
        }
        bool bAnimationActivated = false;
        private void ActivateAnimation()
        {
            if (bAnimationActivated == false)
            {
                AnimateHoverZ(HoverOffset, true);
                bAnimationActivated = true;
            }
        }
        private void DeactivateAnimation()
        {
            if (bAnimationActivated == true)
            {
                AnimateHoverZ(0, false);
                bAnimationActivated = false;
            }
        }

        private void AnimateHoverZ( Double Z, bool HoverUp)
        {
            if (HoverUp == true)
                playAnimation(feTargetObject, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.LocalOffsetZ)", HoverUp_duration, Z, SB_HoverZ, HoverUp_Easing);
            else 
                playAnimation(feTargetObject, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.LocalOffsetZ)", HoverDown_Duration, Z, SB_HoverZ, HoverDown_Easing);
         }
        public static void playAnimation(FrameworkElement element, string property, TimeSpan time, double value, Storyboard sb, IEasingFunction EasingFunction)
        {
            sb = new Storyboard();
            sb.Children.Clear();
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.Duration = time;
            animation.To = value;
            animation.EasingFunction = EasingFunction;
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(property));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, element);
            sb.Children.Add(animation);
            sb.Begin();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Help us help you. What doesn't work? Have you added this behavior to your project and compiled? What have you tried?

Comment: i download this behavior from this link :
http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/MouseOver3D
please look at this link

Comment: have you added the behavior to your project and compiled?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the necessary references (`System.Windows.Interactivity)`
 to your project, for that you need to have some version of the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) installed.

Then to use this in XAML you need to define namespaces for both interactivity and this behavior:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:bs="clr-namespace:Brainsiders.MouseOver3D"
```

Then you should be able to attach it like this:

```xml
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <bs:MouseOver3D />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Comment: when i use namespace in xaml error : The namespace prefix "i" multiply defined and error in cs file : The type or namespace name 'Planprojection' could not be found (are you missing ...)

Comment: Obviously if `i` is already defined you should use another prefix. That second error surely has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @Mohsen: As you probably figured out by now `Projections` only exists in Silverlight.